# Vim regex for wrapping visually selected digits with HTML tags

Tags: vim, html, regex

I have a bunch of text I need to format via HTML, my main problem being that there's a bunch of digits at the beginning of certain words that I need to wrap with HTML tags. I'm trying to think up a vim regex that can help me achieve this but the furthest I've gotten is this:

```
:s:\(\d\):<sup>\1<\/sup>
```

This however only changes the first number in the line and not anything after that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try:

```
:s/\(\d\+\)/<sup>\1<\/sup>/g
```

The 2 problems you had with your command were:

- `\d` matches only one digit. Add a `+` do match more
- The `/g` in the end allows the substitution to continue after the first match.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with the surround plugin for VIM:
https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Your answer does not provide any information why or how the program can answer the question. Please [take a look at these suggestions on how to provide great software recommendations](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I though that the link was self-explanatory.